# Cumulative sum based on a boolean

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, cumsum

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| finalcheck |
| --- |
| False |
| True |
| True |
| True |
| False |
| True |

I want to create another column in this dataframe which gives me a cumulative sum based on finalcheck variable like so:

| finalcheck | position |
| --- | --- |
| False | 1 |
| True | 2 |
| True | 3 |
| True | 4 |
| False | 1 |
| True | 2 |

I have tried multiple ways of achieving this but the closest I could get was by using a groupby with the cumsum function in pandas:

`df['position'] = df.groupby((df.finalcheck).cumsum())`

This did not give me the desired output. Could you help me identify where I am going wrong?

Comment: So you want to start from 1 from each False and increment each "group" while it's True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gap-and-island problem. Every time you encounter a False, you start a new island. Then within each island, you just number the row sequentially:

```py
# The islands
s = df["finalcheck"].eq(False).cumsum()

# Within each island, label the rows sequentially
df['position'] = s.groupby(s).cumcount() + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summ = 0
for i in range(0,len(df)):

    if df["finalcheck"].iloc[i] == "True":
        summ = summ + 1
        df["position"].iloc[i] = summ
    else:
        summ = 0
```

If you're thinking outside of groupby, you can try this